# Python SQLite User query not validating

Tags: python, sqlite

I am writing a python function that takes an input from a user, searches for it in a database and then checks the input against the return result and if correct proceeds with the program and if incorrect asks the user to re-enter. This doesn't work however. When a user enters something it just says it is incorrect as per my program. Here is the code:

```
def TakeOutItem():
Serial = input("Please enter the serial number of the music you are taking out: ")
SerialN = int(Serial,)
with sqlite3.connect("school.db") as db:
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT SerialNo FROM Music WHERE SerialNo=?",(SerialN,))
    data = cursor.fetchone()[0]
    print(">>",SerialN, data,">>")
    print(type(SerialN),type(data)).show
    print(int(SerialN) == int(data))
    if SerialN == int(data):
        DateOut = date.today()
        DateIn = date.today() + timedelta(days=30)
        cursor.execute('SELECT Name FROM Music WHERE SerialNo=?', Serial)
        NameofMusic = cursor.fetchone()
        cursor.execute('SELECT StudentID FROM Student WHERE username=?', student_login(username))
        StudentID = cursor.fetchone()
        cursor.execute('INSERT INTO MusicLoan VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)', DateOut, DateIn, Music, NameofMusic, StudentID)
        print("Item taken out successfully")
        student_menu()

    else:
        print("Incorrect Serial Number please try again")
        TakeOutItem()
```

and this is the error screen

```
What would you like to do?

1. Take out item

2. Return item

3. Exit

Please select an option number: 1

Please enter the serial number of the music you are taking out: 1
>> 1 1 >>
<class 'int'> <class 'int'>
Please select a valid option
```

The it takes me back to he previous menu

How can I fix this error??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cursor.fetchone()` will always return a `tuple`.So use

```
data = cursor.fetchone()[0]
```

**or**

```
if SerialN == data[0]:
```

Inside your `if` condition also, please rewrite it to `NameofMusic[0]` and `StudentID[0]` in your `INSERT` query

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75229/discussion-on-answer-by-itzmeontv-python-sqlite-user-query-not-validating).

Comment: please select a vlid option actually comes from the first bit you see where you get asked if you want to take out an item, return an item or Exit. if you enter anything but a 1,2 or 3 it says invalid option

Also, the select SerialNo is to search the table for the serial  number the user has entered and if found continues on with the program